# Projection of space onto unit sphere - differentiating it!

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> I am trying to differentiate the function that projects each $x\in
>  \mathbb{R}^3$ onto the unit sphere, namely:
>
> $$f(x)=\frac{x}{||x||},\quad f(0)=0$$

I know that the derivative is $$Df\big|_{x}(h)=\frac{x\times (h\times x)}{||x||^3}=\frac{h}{||x||}-\frac{x(x\cdot h)}{||x||^3}$$
But I am having a *lot* of trouble proving it. I can reduce it to:
$$f(x+h)-f(x)-Df\big|_x(h)=x\left(\frac{1}{||x+h||}-\frac{1}{||x||}+\frac{(x\cdot h)}{||x||^3}\right)+o(h)$$
I am struggling to show that the expression in brackets is $o(h)$. It looks like the $||x+h||^{-1}$ is begging for expansion but I'm not sure how to deal with it because they are vectors. Help?

Comment: To say that this function is everywhere smooth, you should really consider defining it on $\mathbb R^3 \backslash \{0\}$ instead of $\mathbb R^3$. On this domain the function has much nicer properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us do the computations in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I also assume $\|\cdot\|$ is the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, for all $x:=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, one has: $$\partial_if(x)=\frac{\|x\|e_i-x\partial_i\|\cdot\|(x)}{\|x\|^2}=\frac{\displaystyle\|x\|e_i-\frac{x_i}{\|x\|}x}{\|x\|^2}=\frac{1}{\|x\|}e_i-\frac{x_i}{\|x\|^3}x.$$
Therefore, for all $x:=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ and for all $h:=(h_1,\ldots,h_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, one gets:

> $$\mathrm{d}f(x)(h)=\sum_{i=1}^n\partial_if(x)h_i=\frac{1}{\|x\|}\sum_{i=1}^nh_ie_i-\frac{1}{\|x\|^3}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_ih_i\right)x=\frac{h}{\|x\|}-\frac{\langle x,h\rangle}{\|x\|^3}x.$$

$\Box$

**WARNING.** I assume $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ when writing: $$\mathrm{d}f(x)(h)=\sum_{i=1}^n\partial_if(x)h_i.$$ The existence of the partial derivatives of $f$ does not suffice to prove that $f$ is differentiable. Some functions admits partial derivatives without being differentiable nor being continuous.

Howeover, it is not hard to show qualitatively that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ (as a quotient). Indeed, $x\mapsto\|x\|$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ as the composition of $t\mapsto\sqrt{t}$ (differentiable on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$) and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\mapsto\|x\|^2\in\mathbb{R}_+^*$ (polynomial in the coordinates).

---

*Remark (computation of the partial derivatives of $\|.\|$).* For all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, one has: $$\|x\|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}.$$
Therefore, for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, one has: $$\partial_i\|\cdot\|(x)=\frac{2x_i}{\displaystyle2\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}}=\frac{x_i}{\|x\|}.$$

Comment: If the partial derivatives are everywhere continuous on a domain which is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, then the function is everywhere $C^1$-differentiable. If you look at your expression of the derivative, this is the case.

Comment: I was not aware of this result, thank you for pointing that out! Howeover, in this case, I think it is preferable to avoid this machinery.

Comment: This is a very basic result in multivariable analysis. You basically estimate $\frac 1{\|h\|}( f(x+h) - f(x) - \nabla f(x)h)$ by using the one-dimensional Taylor theorem in every direction, one by one (because the directional derivatives exists) and by continuity of the partial derivatives, you realize that the whole thing goes to zero. It's not a difficult argument. For instance, in the $2$-dimensional case, you re-write 
$$
f(x_1+h_1,x_2+h_2) - f(x_1,x_2) = f(x_1+h_1,x_2+h_2) - f(x_1+h_1,x_1) + f(x_1+h_1,x_2) - f(x_1,x_2). 
$$

Comment: By the way, your answer is just fine, I am just explaining this for your own information! I +1'ed it.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications, I appreciate that! I keep this result in mind for other times!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Falcon. I've just noticed, the derivative is orthogonal to  $x$ - do you know whether there is a good geometrical reason for this?

Comment: At that moment, the sole geometrical reason I can come with is that at any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, $f$ is directed by $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean computing the gradient restriction of the vector field $x/\|x\|$ defined over all of $\mathbb R^n \{0\}$, on the $(n-1)$-dimensional unit-sphere

The following fact is proved here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1936635/168758.

> **Fact.** Let $M$ be a smooth manifold embedded in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be a differentiable function. Then $f|_M$ is differentiable and $df|_M(x;h) = \langle \mbox{proj}_{T_x M}(\nabla f(x)), h\rangle$, the projection of $\nabla f(x)$ onto $T_xM$, the tangent space of $M$ at $x$

---

In your case, $M = \mathbb S_{n-1} := \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \|x\| = 1\}$, the $(n-1)$-dimensional unit-sphere in $\mathbb R^n$.

One easily computes $T_x M = x^\perp := \{y \in \mathbb R^n \mid y^\top x = 0\}$, and the projection onto $T_x M$ is given by $\mbox{proj}_{T_x M}(v) = \mbox{proj}_{x^\perp}(v) = (I_n - xx^T)v$, for all $x \in M$.

In your specific problem, you have $f(x) := g(x/\|x\|)$ for $x \in \mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ (with arbitrary continuation at $O$). Thus, $\nabla f(x) = g'(x/\|x\|)\cdot \dfrac{I_n-xx^\top/\|x\|^2}{\|x\|} \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$, which is already a vector field on $T_x M$ (i.e no need to project).