# Gradient on sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I would to like to calculate the $\nabla f$, where $f$ is a restriction of the function $F: \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to \mathbb{R} $ to $\mathbb{S^{n}}$.

I know that $\nabla f = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}  g^{ij}\frac{\partial f }{\partial x_{i}} \frac{\partial }{\partial x_{j}}$, where $g^{ij}$ is a inverse matrix of metric coefficients  given by stereo graphic projection. By formation law of the function

$\nabla f = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}  g^{ij}\frac{\partial f }{\partial x_{i}} \frac{\partial }{\partial x_{j}}= \sum_{j=1}^{n}  g^{1j}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{j}}$. However, it is a hard to finish. There exists a short hut for calculating the gradient of function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ and $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is a smooth function. Then

$$\tag{1}\nabla (f|_M) = (\nabla f)^\top,$$

where $\top$ is the projection onto the tangent space of $M$. To see this, note that $\nabla (f|_M)$ is the unique vector fields on $M$ so that

$$ \langle \nabla f|_M , v\rangle = \nabla_v (f|_M), \ \forall v\in TM,$$

where $\nabla_v$ denotes directional derivatives. To check $(1)$, let $x\in M$ and $v\in T_xM$. Then there is a curve $\gamma :(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to M$ so that $\gamma(0)  = x$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$. Thus

$$\nabla_v (f|_M)  =\frac{d}{dt} f(\gamma(t))\bigg|_{t=0}.$$

But the right hand side is also (think of $\gamma $ mapping to $\mathbb R^n$)

$$\langle \nabla f, v\rangle. $$

Thus

$$\langle \nabla (f|_M), v\rangle = \nabla_v f = \langle \nabla f, v\rangle = \langle (\nabla f)^\top, v\rangle \ \ \forall v \Rightarrow \nabla (f|_M) = (\nabla f)^\top.$$